# Kinda singleton in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, singleton, handler

I want to make sure that if one #offer img fired a function attached to event handler then no other #offer img fires another function until the first function finished its job. I figured out that I need kinda Singleton for this.
Here's what I tried to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inProgress = false;
    $('#offer img').mouseover(function (event) {
        if (!inProgress) {
            inProgress = true;

            $('#offer div img').addClass('gray');
            $(event.target).removeClass('gray');

            var clickedId = event.target.id;
            var textId = '#' + clickedId.substr(0, clickedId.search('_'));
            $('.innerContent p:visible').fadeOut(300, function () {
                $(textId).fadeIn();
            });

            inProgress = false;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Not working. What's wrong with this code? 
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inProgress gets set to False immediatley before all your fadeIn and fadeOut functions finish resolving. So your mouseOver function is done, but the fadeIn and fadeOut are not.

If you want inProgress to not be set until the fade in is complete something like

```
        $('.innerContent p:visible').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(textId).fadeIn(300, function(){
                inProgress = false;
            });
        });

    } else {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you :)